# annotated time line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph

I'm working with google annotated time line graphs: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

My question is: I would like to limit the X-axis to show just a range of hours between 5:00 and 21:00. Today I'm showing already per hour but I would like to limit the range and not show 24 hours. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just set the zoomStartTime and zoomEndTime to configure the part of the x axis that is shown?

Something like the following might do it, ie set the start and end date/times and also turn off the range and zoom functions.

```
annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {
                            'displayRangeSelector' : false,
                            'displayZoomButtons': false,
                            'zoomStartTime': new Date(2009, 1 ,2),
                            'zoomEndTime': new Date(2009, 1 ,5)});
```

Just a thought after looking [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line_configuration).

Comment: yes, i fixed long time ago, but i will choose your answer, since its correct.